# Text is not visible when i used a custom drawable layout as a background. my all code is down here

Tags: android

Dont read this starting few lines
it keeps saying your post is mostly code please add description...dont know what to write in it ... i already posted all the relevant content associated with my error.. please help me

MessageAdapter.java (ADAPTER CLASS)

```
 public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{
    private List<Messages> mMessageList;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> mMessageList) {this.mMessageList=mMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public 
    MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout,parent,false);
        return new MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder(v);
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView messageText;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;

        public MessageViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            messageText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
            profileImage=
        (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        String currentUserId=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Messages c=mMessageList.get(position);

        String from_user=c.getFrom();
        if (from_user.equals(currentUserId)){

            holder.messageText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        }else {
                                                                                                             holder.messageText.
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_text_background);
            holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
        holder.messageText.setText(c.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }
    }
```

Messages.java (MODEL CLASS)

```
 public class Messages {


    private String message,type,from;
    private long time;
    private Boolean seen;

    public Messages(String from){
        this.from=from;
    }

    public Messages(String message,boolean seen,long time,String type){

        this.message= message;
        this.seen=seen;
        this.time=time;
        this.type=type;

    }

    public String getMessage() {return message;}

    public void setMessage(String message) {this.message = message;}

    public boolean getSeen() {return seen;}

    public void setSeen(Boolean seen) {this.seen = seen;}

    public long getTime() {return time;}

    public void setTime(long time) {this.time = time;}

    public String getType() {return type;}

    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Messages(){

    }
    }
```

ChatActivity.java(MAIN CLASS)

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String mChatUser;

private String mChatUsername;

private Toolbar mChatToolbar;

private DatabaseReference mRootRef;

private TextView mTitleView;
private TextView mLastSeenView;
private CircleImageView mProfileImage;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

String mCurrentUserId;

private ImageButton mChatAddBtn;
private ImageButton mChatSendBtn;
private EditText mChatMessageView;

private RecyclerView mMessagesList;

private final List<Messages> messagesList=new ArrayList<>();

private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout;

private MessageAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    mChatToolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.chat_app_bar);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUserId=mAuth.getUid();


    setSupportActionBar(mChatToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    mRootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    mChatUser=getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
    mChatUsername=getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");


    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View actionBarView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar,null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);

    mTitleView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_title);
    mLastSeenView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_seen);
    mProfileImage=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_image);

    mChatAddBtn=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat_add_btn);
    mChatSendBtn=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat_send_btn);
    mChatMessageView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.chat_message_view);

    mAdapter=new MessageAdapter(messagesList);

    mMessagesList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.messages_list);

    mLinearLayout=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);

    mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    loadMessages();


    mTitleView.setText(mChatUsername);

    mRootRef.child("users").child(mChatUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String online=dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
            String image=dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();


            if (online.equals("true")){
                mLastSeenView.setText("online");
            }else
            {
                GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo=new GetTimeAgo();
                long lastTime=Long.parseLong(online);
                String lastSeenTime = getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(lastTime,getApplicationContext());
                mLastSeenView.setText(lastSeenTime);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mRootRef.child("chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mChatUser)){

                Map chatAddMap=new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("seen",false);
                chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap=new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("chat/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser,chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("chat/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId,chatAddMap);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mChatSendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });



}

private void loadMessages() {

    mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

private void sendMessage() {

    String message= mChatMessageView.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
        String current_user_ref="messages/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser;
        String chat_user_ref="messages/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId;

        DatabaseReference user_message_push=mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).push();

        String push_id=user_message_push.getKey();

        Map messageMap=new HashMap();
        messageMap.put("messages",message);
        messageMap.put("seen",false);
        messageMap.put("type","text");
        messageMap.put("time",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        messageMap.put("from",mCurrentUserId);

        Map messageUserMap= new HashMap();
        messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref+"/"+push_id,messageMap);
        messageUserMap.put(chat_user_ref+"/"+push_id,messageMap);

        mChatMessageView.setText("");

        mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError!=null){
                    Log.d("chat_log",databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });




    }
}
}
```

MessageLayout.xml (SINGLE MESSAGE LAYOUT)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/message_single_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_profile_layout"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/message_text_background"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MessageTextBackground.xml(SHAPE XML MESSAGE BACKGROUND)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

[Text is Not visible in chat. I used a custom background layout . code is attached above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcVsm.png)

Comment: what does it mean ?? `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_`

Comment: Debug your code check `c.getMessage()` has a `String` or not . if its Ok then there must be something wrong with layout .

Comment: if i am sending message then my mssge background will be different and the person who is replying me,,, his message background will be different

Comment: sorry @LarsH chat is the activity in which people will chat! i dont provided any action for typing..

Comment: @ADM .. i am getting Null Value in c.getMessage() .. can you tell me what should i do now?

Comment: You should debug the steps from starting . I can not guess where exactly is NPE. Check where you use `c.setMessage()`.

Comment: @ADM thanks bud.. atleast i know now that its not retrieving data... thanks alot :)